# Aspnet Core app throws develoeper exception on Production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have hosted AspNetCore app as Azure App service. I have done all the things right but production app still throws developer exceptions.

Code in `Configure` function:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/Error?statusCode={0}");
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
```

Azure App Service Configuration:
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT : Production

Comment: Can you post the exact error message for others to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the environment variable from Azure configuration. The default for `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable is production environment.

Comment: I tried this now but I still see the developer exception. Is there some other place in code or CI/CD where I should check?